# How can I keep previous data in a text file?

Tags: php, html

So basically, I have a form that opens a php file when submitted, i have the php writing to a file, but it will not continue adding values, the text file only has one "1" inside of it when it is supposed to have a "1" inside for every time the form has been submitted. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$myFile = "Data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "1";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: fopen($myFile, 'a+'); ????

Comment: You have to tell us more about the data you want to store in the file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either open in append only format as Robert Rozas stated: `fopen($myFile, 'a+');`

Or get the contents and do the append manually some pseudo[esk]-code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("somefile.txt");
//generate what to write
$contents .= $whatIGenerated;
$success = file_put_contents("somefile.txt", $contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this one line to this:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
```

Using `w` means write, using `a` means append.